# Why doesn't my Chart.js Canvas resize when I use flexbox?

Tags: html, css, charts, flexbox, chart.js

I'm designing a dashboard using Chart.js graphs and Canvases. Please see the dashboard below:

[image: Chart.js Dashboard]

The design is exactly what I want until I resize the page to make it smaller and then resize it again to make it bigger. When I do this I end up with the following:

[image: Chart.js Dashboard after resizing the window to be small then big.]

This did not occur until I added the second chart and made the `div` element containing them both a flexbox. Before making the `div` a flexbox I had the following layout:

[image: Chart.js graphs before resizing without flexbox]

This can easily be resized into the following form for a smaller window:

[image: Chart.js graphs after resizing without flexbox]

and then resized again into the larger form from the previous image. What change has flexbox made that stops the automatic resizing of the charts?

My code is below. HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css_styles/main.css">
  <title>Plus UI Design</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="overview_container">
    <div id="plusPointsContainer" class="points_container-main">
      <div id="plusPointsDoughnut" class="doughnut_holder">
        <canvas id="plusPoints" height="400" width="400"></canvas>
      </div>
      <div class="points_display-horizontal">
        <div class="points_display-vertical">
          <div>
            <div class="points_header">Today:</div>
            50
          </div>
          <div class="points_display-yesterday">
            <div class="points_header-smaller">Yesterday:</div>
            60
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar_chart_container">
      <canvas id="overviewBarGraph" height="400" width="600"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.overview_container {
  display: flex;
}

.bar_chart_container {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
}

.points_container-main {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 400px;
  min-width: 250px;
  max-height: 400px;
  min-height: 250px;
  margin-right: 5vw;
}

.points_display-horizontal {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.points_display-vertical {
  position:relative;
  top: 8%;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue;
    font-size: 70px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.points_display-yesterday {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -10px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.points_header {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}

.points_header-smaller {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-bottom: -3px;
}
```

I have only included the html and css parts as I don't think Javascript is the issue here, but I can update the code section if anyone thinks it is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove from **.points_container-main** and **.bar-chart-container** max-width, min-width styles. Add them styles in flex world:

```
.points_container-main{
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 25%;
}
.bar-chart-container{
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 75%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you elaborate slightly? Why does my way not work and why does your way work?

Comment: You provide size as range from min-width to max-width. Based on that library calculates size of your canvases. When you resize all conditions change - canvases already have size and based n them flex containers stretch in the range from min-width to max-width. That is why it looks different.